# Changing a process' output to ssh terminal

Tags: ssh, gnome-terminal

I have a simple python script:

```
import time
counter = 0
while True:
    print counter
    counter = counter + 1
    time.sleep(10)
```

Let's say this is running on my linuxbox inside LAN and is printing the output to the terminal that linuxbox. If I am to `ssh` into that server, I want to see the status of `counter` variable. In other words, I want to change the I/O of the program from default terminal to `ssh` terminal.

So far I've tried to put the process in background by using `fg` without any luck.

Here's a snapshot (from `ssh` terminal)

```
jarwin@ubuntu:~$ ps -a
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
30412 pts/1    00:00:02 python
30591 pts/10   00:00:00 ps
jarwin@ubuntu:~$ fg %30412
-bash: fg: %30412: no such job
jarwin@ubuntu:~$ top | grep gnome
27337 azazel    20   0  625656  35804  24676 S  0.3  1.4   1:03.01 gnome-terminal-        
jarwin@ubuntu:~$ fg %27337
-bash: fg: %27337: no such job
```

Is it possible to do that? And in case python does not allow that, is it possible to change to `ssh` terminal for a ping command?

PS: I am using [JuiceSSH](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh) on Android as my ssh-client

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can one access an open terminal on the computer via SSH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/940491/can-one-access-an-open-terminal-on-the-computer-via-ssh)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try your luck with [`tmux`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-tmux-on-ubuntu-12-10--2) or [`screen`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen), which allows you to to connect to existing terminal sessions.

The other workaround I would consider is to use some temporary file, where you would write the output (if the output is kind of log) and then follow the new lines in the file using `tail -f`.